# Django's "dumpdata" or Postgres' "pg_dump"?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-backups, dumpdata

I'm unsure as to whether this question should be posted in the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)' section or here, so please advise if I got it wrong.

I have a Django-based website which doesn't change much. I use `python manage.py dumpdata --all --indent=2 > backup.json` and reload the data with `loaddata` if I need to redeploy or the db gets corrupted. (I'm aware about integrity errors that have occurred when not excluding `auth` and `content_types`)

Since I'm using PostgreSQL on the backend, is it "best practise" or "wiser" for me to use `pg_dump` instead, and then `pg_restore` if something goes wrong or if I need to redeploy?

So `dumpdata` dumps all data associated with the selected apps (and/or models), and `pg_dump` performs a full dump of the db. Is this the same thing or is there a fundamental difference that I've missed (mind you I have 0 experience with DBA)?

Which option do I go for and why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is both best practice and wiser for you to use `pg_dump` instead of `dumpdata`.

There are many reasons for this.

- `pg_dump` is faster and the output is more compact (particularly with the -Fc option) than with dumpdata.
- Importing the data back into the db with `pg_restore` will also be faster than django's `loaddata`.
- pg_restore is available on any postgresql installation but django and it's dependencies you will have to install.
- Last but not least the integrity errors that you spoke of will not happen with pg_dump/pg_restore.

Generally pg_dump is used to dump the entire database however the -t option allows you to dump one or few tables at a time

Comment: Noted. I've already written a script to backup using pg_dump executing hourly. Since my DB is really tiny (~30MB), I had not noticed a major performance difference. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome, if you are dumping regularly, you might want to consider using WAL archiving. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not know that PostgreSQL had a continuous backup system. At the moment, I use `pg_dump` and then I commit and push the changes to a private GitHub repo, ensuring incremental changes. I also have the ability to restore data at an point in time, with a worst case scenario of an hour's loss of work. Should I still consider using WAL? Is it worth the effort (time-wise) to implement WAL? It looks a bit complex in comparison to `pg_dump` and `git`. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: yes, it's a bit complex to setup initially in comparision to pg_dump + git but the advantage is that it does not have any impact at all on the performance (dumpdata > pg_dump > WAL). The other point is that you are adding about 600MB each day to your git repo so your bills would keep adding up.

Comment: True, scalability needs to be taken into account, so performance matters. Thanks for the advice (P.S The Git commits only commit the deltas, so it's more on the order of ~1MB per day. But valid point, I'll take it into account)

Comment: only the deltas for text isn't it? I think for binaries it's the whole file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So after a day of running the script hourly, my hosting company reported that I've used 140MB upload, including site traffic. I'm a bit unsure about this situation now. Is it perhaps due to the fact that when I inspect the `pg_dump` file, everything is in plain text? (It's a bunch of sql statements and values, but all human readable)

Comment: Yes, but the diff is still going to be rather large because for every row that is updated, it will store the old record prefixed with a - and the new record prefixed with a + in git.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for that, and for your patience. I'll implement WAL archiving and give it a go. Thanks for the advice